# Проверка существования html элемента на странице

Tags: python

**Код:** (не рабочий)

```
page_html = BeautifulSoup(open("1.htm", "r", encoding="utf-8").read(), "html.parser")

if page_html.select("td")[12] is not None:
    print("oh shit td is gone!")
```

**Задача:**

Нужно вытаскивать текст из `td` но только при условии того что он присутствует на странице (он может и не присутствовать на странице)

Comment: Проверить длину списка с выборкой элементов по заданному условию?

Comment: Да, думаю это пойдёт